# javascript download a file and perform submit action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick javascript function need to perform two actions.

1. download a file with window.location.href = url
2. `document.getElementById('test').submit();`

I am not able to implement both. If the submit function is added, download is not working. Any thoughts on how to achieve both. Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think AJAX causes file downloads.

Comment: If I read this correctly he wants one click to load a page, then submit a form on that page

Comment: Otherwise he needs to submit to an iframe or new window  and load the download to another iframe or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't do that because when submit happens, previous request for that page is closed. People suggest an iframe for file download, but submit will unload old page with iframe in it, so I do not think it will work. Suppose instead of that you should use `window.open(url)` instead of `window.location.href = url` This way you will open completely new window which will download a file and submit will happen in old one.

Comment: The `iframe` is forcing a download, not showing a download page.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Frankly speaking I've never tried something like that. But submit will destroy a page along with iframe. So, what will happen if, for some reason, download request will return after iframe is destroyed?

Comment: This worked. But any workaround with window.location.href. I don't want to prompt download in new page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(" selector ").click(function() {
    $("body").append(
        $("<iframe></iframe>")
        .attr("display", "none")
        .attr("src", url)
    );
    $("#test").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In head

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
function startDownload()
{
var url='http://server/folder/file.ext';  
window.open(url,'Download');
}
</script>
```

In body

```
<button type="button" onclick="startDownload()">Download</button>
```

Comment: you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery